# API - Updating Shopper on BlueSnap

Tags: api, subscription, bluesnap

I need to update a Credit Card on a subscription. Can I update the Shopper and the Subscription on the same call? Or I need to first update the shopper and then the subscription?

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to update a subscription with a new credit card, that is not yet associated with the shopper account, you need to make two API calls:

First, add the credit card to the shopper account by calling the [Update Shopper API](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/update-shopper).

Then, after the card is successfully stored in the shopper account, update the subscription credit card using the [Update Subscription API](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v8976-Extended/docs/update-subscription), while providing the last four digits of the newly added card:

```
<subscription xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
  <credit-card>
    <card-last-four-digits>0126</card-last-four-digits>
  </credit-card>
</subscription>
```